# Which one is best and faster method ?(making drop down method)

Tags: php

I have two different method which help to make drop_down (select) option. Both are work same. only different is in logic for showing selected option

Method 1:

```
function unit_type_drop_down($selected=''){
    $where = array('status'=>'1');
    $unit_type_data = $this->select_result('unit_type', 'id,name', $where);

    $html = '';
    foreach ($unit_type_data as $value) {
        if($value->id == $selected){
             $html.='<option value="' . $value->id . '" selected>' . ucfirst($value->name) . '</option>';
        }else{
             $html.='<option value="' . $value->id . '">' . ucfirst($value->name) . '</option>';
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Method 2:

```
function unit_type_drop_down($selected=''){
    $where = array('status'=>'1');
    $unit_type_data = $this->select_result('unit_type', 'id,name', $where);

    $html = '';
    foreach ($unit_type_data as $value) {
        $html.='<option value="' . $value->id . '">' . ucfirst($value->name) . '</option>';
    }
    $html = str_replace('value="'.$selected.'"', 'value="'.$selected.'" selected="selected"', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

unit type data has value something like

```
$unit_type_data = array(
    array('id'=>1,'name'=>'unit1'),
    array('id'=>1,'name'=>'unit1'),
    array('id'=>1,'name'=>'unit1'),
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    array('id'=>1,'name'=>'unit1')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is faster because `IF-ELSE` statement and string concatenation consume fewer resources and operations than search and replacement in a string.

Of course, if you want to get exact metrics of speed both methods - should calculate [asymptotic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity) for concatenation of strings and replacement string in PHP.

Also, the first method seems more clear to readable than the second method

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getusage](http://php.net/getrusage) to check execution time of any PHP script. Or with [microtime](http://us.php.net/microtime) before and after each script, like this:

```
$before = microtime(true);

// some script

$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before);
```

Comment: this way doesn't show an objective result because of execution time depends on data that used in the test.

Comment: In this case the data would be the same.

Comment: No. One case doesn't show an objective result. What method will be faster if the count of record will be 1000, 100 000, 200 000? You don't spot it with help `getusage`, because you couldn't check all of the cases.

Comment: There is another method in the answer.